# Symfony2 method with query in entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entities: Menu and TypeMenu. In Menu is method

```
public function setTypeId(\Cms\AdminBundle\Entity\TypMenu $typeId = null)
    {
        $this->type_id = $typeId;

        return $this;
    }
```

When I add a new record, I must give method setTypeId, structure in argument.

```
$Menu = new Menu();
...
$TypMenu=$em->getRepository('CmsAdminBundle:TypMenu')->findOneById($form->get('typmenu_id')->getData());

$Menu->setTypeId($TypMenu);
```

It is tiring. In the class Menu I would like create function, which will do it.

```
public function setTypeMenu($id){
         $TypMenu=$em->getRepository('CmsAdminBundle:TypMenu')->findOneById($id);
         return $this->setTypeId($TypeMenu);
     }
```

I read that doctrine in entity isn't optimal.

How I can achieve it?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself a MenuFactory, inject the necessary repositories then move your create code to it.

```
// In a controller
$menuFactory = $this->get('menu.factory');
$menu = $menuFactory->createForTyp($typId);

// The factory
class MenuFactory
{
    $typMenuRepository;

    public function __construct($typMenuRepository)
    {
        $this->typMenuRepository = $typMenuRepository;
    }
    public createFromTypMenu($typId)
    {
        $menu = new Menu();
        $typMenu = $this->typMenuRepository->findOneById($typId);
        $menu->setTyp($typMenu);
        return $menu;
    }
}

// Wire it up in services.yml
services:
  typmenu.repository
    class Bundle\Entity\TypMenuRepository
    factory_service: 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
    factory_method:  'getRepository'
    arguments:  
        - 'Bundle\Entity\TypMenu'

  menu.factory:
    class: Bundle\MenuFactory
    arguments: ['@typmenu.repository]
```

Once you get the hang of it, this stuff becomes second nature.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

I was a bit puzzled by your use of $form in your question as well as typ_id.  With Doctrine 2 you deal mostly with objects.  You seldom need id's at the controller level.  Might also want to review the chapters on Doctrine and Forms in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to request the whole entity from repository like this, it takes resources for no reason if you don't use any field of the TypMenu entity you better use :

```
 $Menu->setTypeId($em->getReference('CmsAdminBundle:TypMenu', $id));
```

this is optimal already i don't know any better way, again if you are not using any data from TypMenu don't use the repository use the reference.